# get weather from weather api and setState inoto array of objects in react native

Tags: react-native, fetch, setstate, weather-api

This is my state. I want to get `lat` and `long` from all objects in the `state` and get their current weather and then set their `temperature` into temperature state. Can anybody please help me with this?

```
class App extends React.Component{
        this.state = {
              data: [
                {
                  id: 1,
                  lat: "35.6892" ,
                  long: "51.3890",
                  temperature: '',
                },
                {
                  id: 2,
                  lat: "45.6892" ,
                  long: "35.3890",
                  temperature: '',
                },
                {
                  id: 3,
                  lat: "59.6892" ,
                  long: "-72.3890",
                  temperature: '',
                },
                {
                  id: 4,
                  lat: "23.6892" ,
                  long: "-52.3890",
                  temperature: '',
                },
        
            componentDidMount() {
                
                for(var i =0 ; i<= this.state.data.length - 1 ; i++) {
            
                   let url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + this.state.data[i].lat + '&lon=' + this.state.data[i].long + '&units=metric&appid=api key';
                
                  fetch(url)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        this.setState.data((prevState, props) => ({
                            temperature: data.main.temp
                    }));
                    })
                }
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though using a fetch request inside of a for loop is never a good idea as if the number of element increase, there will a lot of fetch request to the server which will eventually make the process slower. Still if you want to do this try the code described bellow:

```
for(var i =0 ; i<= this.state.data.length - 1 ; i++) {
        
    let url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + this.state.data[i].lat + '&lon=' + this.state.data[i].long + '&units=metric&appid=api key';
            
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
          // 1. Make a shallow copy of the items
          let items = [...this.state.data];

          // 2. Make a shallow copy of the item you want to mutate
          let item = {...items[1]};

          // 3. Replace the property you're intested in
          item.temperature = data.main.temp;

          // 4. Put it back into our array. N.B. we *are* mutating the array here, but that's why we made a copy first
          items[1] = item;

           // 5. Set the state to our new copy
           this.setState({items});
      })
   }
```

Comment: thank you for your response. what i want do is i have some cities in my state with their lat & long. i want to get the temperature of each city and show them in my app . if there is a better idea i would be really happy to know what?

Comment: If you want to get temperature for all cities at a time and given the scenario that there are only few cities, then you can proceed with a Fetch call in for loop. But considering the scenario that there are lots of cities, then call api in a for loop will reduce the performance. In that case, I will suggest to use an api where you can get all the cities weather update with a single Fetch call. As working with json in your application is less costly then calling API in a for loop.

Comment: no there are lots of cities. i want to show all cities in a FlatList. but i want the temperature of each city to show user.

Comment: In that case, its better you seek for a api where you can get all the cities weather information in one api call. Fetch them in a single api call, store in a variable and show it as you like. Otherwise if you try to call for each one in a loop, it will cost you a lot of bandwidth and will reduce the performance.